# Thinkpad disable TrackPoint

Tags: xorg, arch-linux, mouse, thinkpad, synclient

I have a new thinkpad x220t running Arch Linux.
There seems to be a problem in the products hardware architecture as the TrackPoint is moving when you convert the thinkpad into tablet mode and put pressure on the screen. 
Therefore I'd like to toggle the TrackPoint using a little bash script called by ACPId. 
I so far wrote this code snippet which disables the TouchPad, but not the TrackPoint (aka. Clit Mouse).

```
#!/bin/sh

status=`synclient|awk '/TouchpadOff/{printf$3}'`
status=`expr \( $status + 1 \) \% 2`
synclient TouchpadOff=$status
```

Is there any possibility to toggle the TrackPoint Status using a bash script?

Comment: I think we should close this question as EVIL. Disabling the TrackPoint stands as an affront to God himself.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try `xinput`. First list the devices, so you can find out how the TrackPoint is called: `xinput list`. For this example I'll use my logitech mouse which goes by the string "Logitech USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse". You have to replace the string with the correct one for your TrackPoint, of course. Now I can disable the mouse with: `xinput set-prop "Logitech USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse" "Device Enabled" 0` and enable it again with: `xinput set-prop "Logitech USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse" "Device Enabled" 1`.

Comment: Perfect Thank you very much. The Device Name is "TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint" for any future use.

Comment: Just disabled my "AlpsPS/2 ALPS DualPoint Stick"; it was moving without provocation. Thanks a ton for this snippet!